# Error in Karma Unit Test: TypeError: event.preventDefault is not a function error

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, frontend, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test this function:

```
@HostListener("keydown", [$event])
onKeyDown(event){
 if(event.keyCode===32 || event.keyCode===13){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.nameClicked.emit(this.name);
 }
}
```

However, I received this error in Karma: TypeError: event.preventDefault is not a function error.

This is the code for my unit test:

```
it("should emit name and call onKeyDown when pressed:, () => {

  const spy = spyOn(component.nameClicked, "emit");

  const event = {keyCode: 13};

  component.onKeyDown(event);

  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();

 });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, just edited the question.

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Where does `HostListener` come from? How does `nameClicked` property declare?